# How to coerce a character column to a list column

Tags: r

I am trying to bind data frames rows.  I generate some data frame with list columns after aggregation but some are character.  I can't find a way to bind them.  I tried converting the character column using `as.list()` but that didn't work.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),stringsAsFactors = F)
df1$b <-  list(c("1","2"),"4",c("5","6"))
> df1
  a    b
1 1 1, 2
2 2    4
3 3 5, 6
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(4,5),b=c("9","12"),stringsAsFactors = F)
> df2
  a  b
1 4  9
2 5 12
dplyr::bind_rows(df2,df1)
Error in bind_rows_(x, .id) : 
  Column `b` can't be converted from character to list
```

Comment: you can use `rbind(df2, df1)` - note that it will turn the "b" column into a list. Currently `df1` has a numeric and list columns and `df2` has a numeric and character columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the `dplyr` library well, but using base R's `rbind()` below seems to be working:

```
df1 <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),stringsAsFactors = F)
df1$b <-  list(c("1","2"),"4",c("5","6"))
df2 <- data.frame(a=c(4,5),b=c("9","12"),stringsAsFactors = F)

result <- rbind(df1, df2)

class(result$a)
[1] "numeric"
class(result$b)
[1] "list"
```

## Demo

If you wanted to get this working with `bind_rows()`, start by looking at the error message.  It looks like `dplyr` doesn't like that one data frame has character data while the other has list data.  You could try converting the character column to list and then call `bind_rows`, e.g.

```
df2$b <- as.list(df2$b)
dplyr::bind_rows(df2,df1)
```

Comment: yes. that works.  I've been using  dplyr::bind_rows because the data frames are messy and some are missing some columns.  Any idea how to make this work with bind_rows? Maybe gtools::smartbind...

Comment: @Eric Could you try my suggestion for `bind_rows` and let me know if it worked.  If not, maybe someone else has a direct fix for you.